# Vaadin - Button not doing anything

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, vaadin, tomcat9

I have a application developed in Vaadin, SpringBoot and Java running in a docker container.

My problem is that one of the buttons is not doing anything or if it is doing something then I think that an exception is being thrown.

If the last scenario is what indeed is happening, where can I consult my printed messages? Note that my application is being deployed to Tomcat.

In my application I have a view

### View

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Route(value = "categories", layout = MainLayout.class)
@PageTitle("Categories | Vaadin CRM")
@PermitAll
public class CategoryView extends VerticalLayout {
    Grid<Category> grid = new Grid<>(Category.class);
    TextField filterText = new TextField();
    CategoryForm form;
    CrmService service;

    public CategoryView(CrmService service) {
        this.service = service;
        addClassName("category-view");
        setSizeFull();
        configureGrid();

        form = new CategoryForm();
        form.setWidth("25em");
        form.addListener(CategoryForm.SaveEvent.class, this::saveCategory);
        form.addListener(CategoryForm.DeleteEvent.class, this::deleteCategory);
        form.addListener(CategoryForm.CloseEvent.class, e -> closeEditor());

        FlexLayout content = new FlexLayout(grid, form);
        content.setFlexGrow(2, grid);
        content.setFlexGrow(1, form);
        content.setFlexShrink(0, form);
        content.addClassNames("content", "gap-m");
        content.setSizeFull();

        add(getToolbar(), content);
        updateList();
        closeEditor();
        grid.asSingleSelect()
                .addValueChangeListener(event -> editCategory(event.getValue()));
    }

    private void configureGrid() {
        grid.addClassNames("category-grid");
        grid.setSizeFull();
        grid.setColumns("description");
        grid.getColumns().forEach(col -> col.setAutoWidth(true));
    }

    private HorizontalLayout getToolbar() {
        filterText.setPlaceholder("Filter by description...");
        filterText.setClearButtonVisible(true);
        filterText.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY);
        filterText.addValueChangeListener(e -> updateList());

        Button addCategoryButton = new Button("Add category");
        addCategoryButton.addClickListener(click -> addCategory());

        HorizontalLayout toolbar =
                new HorizontalLayout(filterText, addCategoryButton);
        toolbar.addClassName("toolbar");
        return toolbar;
    }

    private void saveCategory(CategoryForm.SaveEvent event) {
        service.saveCategory(event.getCategory());
        updateList();
        closeEditor();
    }

    private void deleteCategory(CategoryForm.DeleteEvent event) {
        service.deleteCategory(event.getCategory());
        updateList();
        closeEditor();
    }

    public void editCategory(Category category) {
        if (category == null) {
            closeEditor();
        } else {
            form.setCategory(category);
            form.setVisible(true);
            addClassName("editing");
        }
    }

    void addCategory() {
        grid.asSingleSelect().clear();
        editCategory(new Category());
    }

    private void closeEditor() {
        form.setCategory(null);
        form.setVisible(false);
        removeClassName("editing");
    }

    private void updateList() {
        grid.setItems(service.findAllCategories(filterText.getValue()));
    }


}
```

And this view uses a form for when I want to add a category

### Form

```
public class CategoryForm extends FormLayout {
    TextField description = new TextField("Description");
    Binder<Category> binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(Category.class);
    Button save = new Button("Save");
    Button delete = new Button("Delete");
    Button close = new Button("Cancel");
    private Category category;

    public CategoryForm() {
        addClassName("category-form");
        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);
        add(description, createButtonsLayout());
    }

    private HorizontalLayout createButtonsLayout() {
        save.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);
        delete.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_ERROR);
        close.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_TERTIARY);

        save.addClickShortcut(Key.ENTER);
        close.addClickShortcut(Key.ESCAPE);

        save.addClickListener(event -> validateAndSave());
        delete.addClickListener(
                event -> fireEvent(new DeleteEvent(this, category)));
        close.addClickListener(event -> fireEvent(new CloseEvent(this)));


        binder.addStatusChangeListener(e -> save.setEnabled(binder.isValid()));

        return new HorizontalLayout(save, delete, close);
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
        binder.readBean(category);
    }

    private void validateAndSave() {
        try {
            binder.writeBean(category);
            fireEvent(new SaveEvent(this, category));
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("ERRO");
        }
    }

    public <T extends ComponentEvent<?>> Registration addListener(
            Class<T> eventType, ComponentEventListener<T> listener) {
        return getEventBus().addListener(eventType, listener);
    }

    // Events
    public static abstract class CategoryFormEvent
            extends ComponentEvent<CategoryForm> {
        private final Category category;

        protected CategoryFormEvent(CategoryForm source, Category category) {
            super(source, false);
            this.category = category;
        }

        public Category getCategory() {
            return category;
        }
    }

    public static class SaveEvent extends CategoryFormEvent {
        SaveEvent(CategoryForm source, Category category) {
            super(source, category);
        }
    }

    public static class DeleteEvent extends CategoryFormEvent {
        DeleteEvent(CategoryForm source, Category category) {
            super(source, category);
        }

    }

    public static class CloseEvent extends CategoryFormEvent {
        CloseEvent(CategoryForm source) {
            super(source, null);
        }
    }
```

### Service

```
@Service
public class CrmService {

    private final ContactRepository contactRepository;
    private final CompanyRepository companyRepository;
    private final StatusRepository statusRepository;
    private final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public CrmService(ContactRepository contactRepository,
                      CompanyRepository companyRepository,
                      StatusRepository statusRepository,
                      CategoryRepository categoryRepository,
                      CustomerRepository customerRepository){
        this.contactRepository = contactRepository;
        this.companyRepository = companyRepository;
        this.statusRepository = statusRepository;
        this.categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

     public List<Category> findAllCategories(String stringFilter) {
        if (stringFilter == null || stringFilter.isEmpty()) {
            return categoryRepository.findAll();
        } else {
            return categoryRepository.search(stringFilter);
        }
    }


    public void deleteCategory(Category category) {
        categoryRepository.delete(category);
    }

    public void saveCategory(Category category) {
        if (category == null) {
            System.err.println(
                    "Category is null. Are you sure you have connected your form to the application?");
            return;
        }
        categoryRepository.save(category);
    }
}
```

### Repository

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer> {

    @Query("select c from Category c " +
        "where lower(c.description) like lower(concat('%', :searchTerm, '%')) ")
    List<Category> search(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm);

}
```

Is there any way to debug what is indeed happening?

Comment: You are not telling which of the buttons is not working.

Comment: You have so see where the log messages are sent to. Just guessing that perhaps an exception is thrown won't help any of us here

Comment: Have you checked server.log in tomcat for messages?

Comment: You should be able to debug you application in your ide. How to do it depends on your IDE, build-system etc. I find it easiest to use Vaadin with Spring Boot and build with Maven. If you don't need Spring or CDI you can run in Jetty for development purposes with a maven plugin, there are plenty examples to find out there, just search for "jetty vaadin"

Comment: You can view the docker container's standard out log (if you reach it from command line) with command: `docker logs -f [container_id]` . To view your container id use the:`docker ps` command.
Example: `docker logs -f 45755fb106b4` // the -f option is the follow mode, refreshing the log in real time, the 455... is the container id which will probably different in your case